# Calculation of a twisted ribbon in space

Tags: geometry

I have two cylinders with different diameters. The cylinders are positioned in the space as follows:

[image]

A rubber band wraps around the cylinders.

I need to develop a computer algorithm to calculate the position and twisting of the rubber band in space. I would like to approximate the rubber band by a simple mesh as shown in the sketch (i.e. the edges of the rubber band are approximated by polylines).

In the example shown here the cylinder axes do not intersect and are rotated by 90 degrees against each other. There will be cases where the axes might intersect at a very low angle and/or the axis are rotated against each other by an angle which differs from 90 degrees.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete remodeling of my previous answer.

Take a look at Fig. 1.

[image]

Fig. 1.

This figure represents the central part of the rubber band constituted of 2 circle arcs (in blue) and 2 **cubic Bezier curves** connecting them (in red and black resp.), preserving not only continuity but also the differentiability at the connecting points between circular arcs and Bezier curves. The left cylinder has been tilted from an initial vertical position by an angle $a$ 
 ($a=\pi/6$ here) around $Ox$ axis represented here splitting the horizontal plane into two parts. The right cylinder has been tilted by an opposite angle $-a$.

The four points that define one of the Bezier curve (the red one) are pictured as small circles. Two of them are clearly obtained as endpoints of the circular arcs, the other two are obtained by approximating speed vectors at the said endpoints.

You will find at the end the Matlab program that has generated Fig. 1.

Fig. 2 is a compulsory aid in order to understand the situation before the cylinders are tilted and the numerous implementation details :

[image]

Fig. 2.

Remark : the conventions taken are WLOG (Without Loss Of Generality) : in particular, Ox axis has been selected as directed by the shortest line segment between the cylinders. And through this axis, there always exists a plane such that the axes of the two cylinders make angles $\pm a$ with this plane.

```
 function rubberband;
 clear all,close all;hold on;axis equal;
 LW='linewidth';
 x1=5;x2=12;% abscissas of centers
 a=pi/6;% angle under which the circles are seen from 0
 sa=sin(a);r1=x1*sa;r2=x2*sa;
 view([4,6]);
 co=50;
 b=pi/6;%tilt angle of cylinders
 h=1;% cylinders half height
 R1=[1,0,0;
      0,cos(b),-sin(b);
      0,sin(b),cos(b)];% rotation matrix around Ox
 R2=inv(R1);
 % The horizontal plane:
 D=9;fill3(D*[-1,1,1,-1,-1]+10,D*[-1,-1,1,1,-1],...
 zeros(1,5),'c','edgecolor','b','facealpha',0.5);
 plot3([0,2*D],[0,0],[0,0]);% x axis
 text(0,0,0.3,'0');% origin O
 t1=(pi/2+a):0.01:(3*pi/2-a);
 t2=fliplr((-pi/2-a):0.01:(pi/2+a));
 L1=length(t1);
 L2=length(t2);
 arc1=R1*[x1+r1*cos(t1);r1*sin(t1);zeros(1,L1)];
 arc1=R1*arc1;
 B=arc1(:,L1);plot3(B(1),B(2),B(3),'or');
 Bb=arc1(:,L1-1);
 VB=B+co*(B-Bb);plot3(VB(1),VB(2),VB(3),'or')
 rc2=[x2+r2*cos(t2);r2*sin(t2);zeros(1,L2)];
 arc2=R2*arc2;
 E=arc2(:,L2);plot3(E(1),E(2),E(3),'or');
 Eb=arc2(:,L2-1);
 VE=E+co*(E-Eb);plot3(VE(1),VE(2),VE(3),'or')
 % the two circle arcs:
 plot3(arc1(1,:),arc1(2,:),arc1(3,:),'b',LW,2)
 plot3(arc2(1,:),arc2(2,:),arc2(3,:),'b',LW,2)
 % the two cubic Bezier curves (see function below):
 bez(B,E,VB,VE,'r',0);
 bez(B,E,VB,VE,'k',1);
 % Cylinders plot:
 Cyu=[x1+r1*cos(t1);r1*sin(t1);h*ones(1,L1)];%up
 Cyb=[x1+r1*cos(t1);r1*sin(t1);-h*ones(1,L1)];%bottom
 Cy=R1*[Cyu,Cyb];
 for q=1:10:L1;
     plot3(Cy(1,[q,q+L1]),Cy(2,[q,q+L1]),Cy(3,[q,q+L1]),LW,2);
 end;
 Cyu=[x2+r2*cos(t2);r2*sin(t2);h*ones(1,L2)];%up
 Cyb=[x2+r2*cos(t2);r2*sin(t2);-h*ones(1,L2)];%bottom
 Cy=R2*[Cyu,Cyb];
 for q=1:5:L2;
     plot3(Cy(1,[q,q+L2]),Cy(2,[q,q+L2]),Cy(3,[q,q+L2]),LW,2);
 end;
 %
 function bez(B,E,VB,VE,col,sym);
 t=0:0.01:1;s=1-t;
 P=B*(s.^3)+3*VB*((s.^2).*t)+3*VE*((t.^2).*s)+E*(t.^3);
 if sym
     P=diag([1,-1,-1])*P;% symmetry wrt Ox axis
 end;
 plot3(P(1,:),P(2,:),P(3,:),'linewidth',2,'color',col)
```

Comment: Nice picture. But I think the ribbon (if it has to model what really happens) will not be wrapped around the cylinders along a circle arc, but rather something like an ellipse, as I expect it to be bent at different directions on the two sides.

Comment: @Aretino : Interesting remark. The model I provide can rather easily be adapted to cope with this ellipse (or helix ?) arc. As the OP hasn't specified anything on this respect (It is likely that he/she is looking for a "aesthetically fine looking" of the ribbon rather than be on the "physically plausible" side)

Comment: @Aretino : the solution I propose corresponds to the "shortest distance" case. In other cases, yes, one must consider an helical (?) wrapping on the cylinder. It reminds us of the pictures showing the interior of XIXth century factories...

Comment: I think this is a minimum problem: the rubber band wraps around the cylinders so that its total length be minimum. You may be right about the helix, but my favorite solution is planar, formed by two ellipse arcs joined by two segments, all lying in a plane tilted at 45° with respect to cylinders axes. I'll post a question about this.

Comment: @Aretino Interesting exchange. I will have a look at your question. I have had a quick look at practitioners with keywords "belts" and (cylindrical) "pulleys" : I found nothing about the "wrapping curve" on the pulleys.

Comment: Here's my question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2706757/a-rubber-band-around-two-cylinders

Comment: @Jean Marie: Thank you for your suggestion. I am not sure if I understand you correctly. Where are T1, T1' and T2, T2'?

Comment: $T_1$ and $T'_1$ are the 2 points where the center line of the rubber band leaves sphere nr 1 or cylinder nr 1. The same for $T_2$ and $T'_2$ with resp. to sphere nr 2.

Comment: I have written an alternate solution.